# How can I remove the special characters from list of string using plsql procedures

Tags: mysql

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
      SET @str = '(remove) ~special~ *characters. from string in sql!'
      WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
          SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
```

I tried with the above sample code but it showing some syntax error

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? Did you read the error message?

Comment: Am using MySql only this is respected error I got       ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@str VARCHAR(400);